# tkinter in Spyder

Tags: python, tkinter, spyder

I am trying my first steps in `tkinter`. I use `Spyder` as IDE in Python 3.5.1, by way of Anaconda 4.0.0.

I want to run the very simple script below but it always crashes my Spyder. In a normal shell/Bash it runs though and opens the canvas.

```
import tkinter as tkr

tk = tkr.Tk()
canvas = tkr.Canvas(tk, width=500, height=500)
canvas.grid()
tk.mainloop()
```

Under `Preferences` for the Ipython Console I already tried different settings (i.e. Qt, Automatik, Tkinter) but none of it did help.

What am I doing wrong (and how can I do it better)?

Comment: Problem solved by upgrading to Spyder 5.3.3, Thankyouverymuch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

update to Spyder 3.0.1

https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/

https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases/tag/v3.0.1

I just did this on win 10: no crash, got blank "tk" separate window

Comment: thanks @f5r5e5d, that solved it indeed. On my OSX it was still Spyder 2.3.9. despite downloading the latest anaconda update.

Answer (score 3):

You should try to change the graphics backend
Go to tools/preferences/I-python Console/Graphics and in backend change it to Tkinter.
That should do it!!

Answer (score 2):

- In the Spider menu bar, go to: **Tools** > **Preferences**
- A window will open, then on left side go to: **Completion and linting**
- In the right side, go to: **introspection** and below you will see different modules available in your current spider
- In the section "Preload the following modules...", add **tkinter** to the end of the list

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found this suggestion while trying to get tkinter to display a GIF image in a label. First, on a Mac, the Tools menu item does not contain Preferences--look under the "python" menu instead.  Even so, I have the
IPython Console Graphics backend set to Tkinter and tkinter is added to Completion and Linting.  But all I get when launching from Spyder is an empty frame entitled "tk #442", whereas when I launch from the command line I get a frame with a nice GIF image as expected.